# Dealing with exponents during infix to prefix conversion

Tags: python

I am trying to convert something from infix to prefix notation. For example, I want

```
A1 + B1
```

to look like:

```
add A1 B1
```

I have this code:

```
class Type(Enum):  # This could also be done with individual classes
    leftparentheses = 0
    rightparentheses = 1
    operator = 2
    empty = 3
    operand = 4
    negOperator = 5
    comma = 6
    exp = 7

OPERATORS = {  # get your data out of your code...
    "+": "add",
    "-": "subtract",
    "*": "multiply",
    "%": "modulus",
    "/": "safeDiv",
}

def textOperator(string):
    if string not in OPERATORS:
        sys.exit("Unknown operator: " + string)
    return OPERATORS[string]

def typeof(string):
    if string == '(':
        return Type.leftparentheses
    elif string == ')':
        return Type.rightparentheses
    elif string == ',':
        return Type.comma
    elif string == '^':
        return Type.exp
    elif string in OPERATORS:
        return Type.operator
    elif string == ' ':
        return Type.empty
    else:
        return Type.operand

def process(tokens):

    stack = []
    previousTokenCategory = Type.leftparentheses

    while tokens:
        token = tokens.pop()

        category = typeof(token)

#ignore negative signs from negative numbers
        if previousTokenCategory == Type.leftparentheses or previousTokenCategory == Type.operator:
            if token == "-":
                category = Type.operand

        #print("token = ", token, " (" + str(category) + ")")

        if category == Type.operand:
            stack.append(token)
            temp = ''.join(stack)
            while len(stack) > 0 :
                stack.pop()
            stack.append(temp)
            previousTokenCategory = Type.operand
        elif category == Type.operator:
            stack.append((textOperator(token), stack.pop(), process(tokens)))
            previousTokenCategory = Type.operator
        elif category == Type.exp:
            stack.append(("exp", stack.pop(), process(tokens)))
            previousTokenCategory = Type.exp
        elif category == Type.leftparentheses:
            stack.append(process(tokens))
            previousTokenCategory = Type.leftparentheses
        elif category == Type.rightparentheses:
            previousTokenCategory = Type.rightparentheses
            return stack.pop()
        elif category == Type.empty:
            continue

    return stack.pop()

INFIX = "(1 + ((C24 + A2) * (B2 - F4))"
postfix = process(list(INFIX[::-1]))
```

This works great when I don't have exponents. For example "(1 + ((C24 + A2) * (B2 - F4))" is converted to:

```
('add', '1', ('multiply', ('add', 'C24', 'A2'), ('subtract', 'B2', 'F4')))
```

But when I have exponents, it doesn't work. For example, when I have this: "(1 + ((C24 + A2)^2 * (B2 - F4))" it converts it to this:

```
('add', '1', ('exp', ('add', 'C24', 'A2'), ('multiply', '2', ('subtract', 'B2', 'F4'))))
```

even though the right output should be this:

```
('add', '1', ('multiply', ('exp', ('add', 'C24', 'A2'), 2), ('subtract', 'B2', 'F4')))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code doesn't appear to do anything to handle order of operations (operator precedence), so it also produces incorrect results for simpler expressions like `(1 + 3*A2+B2)`.  It works on your exponent example if you enclose the exponentiation in parentheses.  If you want to handle operator precedence, you'll have to rethink your approach somewhat.

Comment: Why aren't you treating exponent as an operator?

Comment: I have tried treating "^" as an operator as well and in that case, I get this: 'add', '1', ('exp', ('add', 'C24', 'A2'), ('multiply', '2', ('subtract', 'B2', 'F4')))) eitherway, the answer is wrong

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `tokens.pop(0)`, then the list doesn't need to be reversed when process is first called.
2. When trying to debug a state machine like this, it is often helpful to print or log the state when changing the stack: print(stack[-3:], category, tokens[:3]).
3. As BrenBarn commented, your function doesn't account for the idea that '^' comes before '*' and ''/', which comes before '+' and '-', etc.  This is called operator precedence.  In your function, `stack.append(("exp", stack.pop(), process(tokens)))` causes everything after the `^` to be processed as the exponent.

One way to tackle this is to use 2 stacks: an operator stack and an operand stack.

```
For each token
    If its an operand, push it on the operand stack
    If its an operator, compare it with the operator on the top of the operator stack
        If the operator on the stack has lower precedence, then
            push the new operator on the stack
        If the operator on the stack has higher or equal precedence, then 
            pop the operator and its operands off the stacks
            apply the operator to the operands, and
            push the result back on the operand stack
            push the new operator on the operator stack
    If it's a '(' push it on the operator stack
    If it's a ')' pop and apply operators to operands until a '(' is on 
        the top of the operator stack, then pop the '('.
    If its the end of the input, apply the operators to the operands.  At the 
        end, the operand stack should be empty and the operand stack should
        just have the final result on it.
```

Example: "1 + (C24 + A2)^2 * (B2 - F4)"

just before processing the first ')', the stacks look like:

```
operators = ['+', '(', '+']
operands = ['1', 'C24', 'A2']
token = ')'
```

'+' is higher than ')', so apply the '+' to the top of the operand stack to get:

```
operators = ['+', '(']
operands = ['1', ('add', 'C24', 'A2')]
token = ')'
```

token is ')' and top of operator stack is ')', so pop the '(', and get the next token.

```
operators = ['+']
operands = ['1', ('add', 'C24', 'A2')]
token = '^'
```

'+' is lower precedence than '^', so push the '^' on the stack. The '2' will get pushed on the operand stack.

```
operators = ['+', '^']
operands = ['1', ('add', 'C24', 'A2'), '2']
token = '*'
```

Now '^' is higher precedence than '*', so apply it to the stacks to get:

```
operators = ['+']
operands = ['1', ('exp', ('add', 'C24', 'A2'), '2')]
token = '('
```

and so on